# strange behavior with linux sort

Tags: linux, sorting

I think there is probably some explanation but I just do not understand why it is behaving like this:

```
$ sort -k 2 -t "|" tests/resources/event1.txt
20180611|10|2|edf|8|abc
20180611|1|2|edf|1|abc
20180611|15|2|edf|15|abc
20180611|2|2|edf|2|abc
20180611|5|2|edf|1|abc
20180611|6|2|edf|1|abc
20180611|7|2|edf|8|abc
20180611|8|2|edf|3|abc
```

So why 10 comes before 1 and then 1 comes before 15? Either I should have 10, 15, 1 or 1,10,15 right? Why mixed up like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man sort`:

```
-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
       start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line)
```

You are starting a key at the second column, but it continues to the end of the line.
So for the 3 lines you asked about, the keys are:

```
102edf8abc
12edf1abc
152edf15abc
```

Looks sorted to me.

Perhaps you wanted `-k 2,2`?

Comment: Thx. next time I will read man page better then

Comment: But still why does the sort come out with that order i pasted?

Comment: I think I answered that.  Read the part about the actual keys your sort is using.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your command is that it considers the values as strings and sort accordingly which is correct in a way as 1 comes before 2. just add `-n` to your command which stands for `Compare according to string numerical value` or use the below command:

```
$ sort -n -k 2 -t "|" tests/resources/event1.txt
```

Output:

```
20180611|1|2|edf|1|abc
20180611|2|2|edf|2|abc
20180611|5|2|edf|1|abc
20180611|6|2|edf|1|abc
20180611|7|2|edf|8|abc
20180611|8|2|edf|3|abc
20180611|10|2|edf|8|abc
20180611|15|2|edf|15|abc
```

I hope this explains your questions.